# Utility for selectively copying source project

Tags: file-management

I need some tool.

I have project (Java/Android). At folder src I have all my java files. I made some changes in the project (some files changed). Now I want copy from src all updated files (for example: today changes), but preserving the directory structure.

For example, I haved:

```
src\dir1\file1.java 
         file2.java (updated)
   \dir2\file3.java (updated)
   \dir2\dir3\file4.java
```

after coping I want to get new src folder with struct:

```
(some folder)\dir1\file2.java
             \dir2\file3.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use command line tool: xcopy or robocopy.
My best way: Total Commander + CopyTree.